# Phrase for people who make unrecognized contributions

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am seeking a better way to convey "people who help in so many ways yet, remain largely unrecognized," so that we can recognize and award them as a special group at our meetings. The words previously used were "Under the Radar Award".

Comment: Sounds like you want an [unsung hero](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unsung-hero) award.

Comment: If the contributions are unrecognized then by identifying them won't you make them recognized, and thus instantly make the term meaningless?

Comment: Outing the Anonymous Donors?

Comment: Unrecognized? If anyone is unrecognized, they should announce themself!

Comment: With this kind of award, you inevitably have to recognize some people but not others. The net effect can be divisive.  To my mind, the present “under the radar” title seems less likely to generate resentment.

Comment: Please see  [this guidance from Stack Exchange Management](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity) about such questions. We are not a word-puzzle and crossword puzzle site; we're a site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English-language enthusiasts.

Answer (score 0):

Behind the Scenes.

I often use this term to talk about leaders, interns, and even bosses when certain work of theirs goes unnoticed. It has served it's purpose many times, and I'll often use it to help recognize people during large events.